# Setting up multinode hadoop cluster Blockpool ID mismatch

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

While setting up multinode hadoop cluster I faced up several issues.
Going through different web portals for correct setup. Some fundamental question arose
I am using **Hadoop 2.8.5** to set up a 2 node cluster in master slave configuration.
On first machine format the namenode using `hdfs namenode format`

`clusterID` and `BlockpoolID` got assigned like below:

```
#Fri Mar 29 11:14:41 IST 2019
namespaceID=576041649
clusterID=CID-98480e8d-f7a9-4e1a-8997-400a7aa150c3
cTime=1553838281164
storageType=NAME_NODE
blockpoolID=BP-954411427-x.x.x.y-1553838281164
layoutVersion=-63
```

Now on the 2nd machine, I ran command `hdfs namenode format -clusterId CID-98480e8d-f7a9-4e1a-8997-400a7aa150c3`

```
#Fri Mar 29 11:15:38 IST 2019
namespaceID=304822257
clusterID=CID-98480e8d-f7a9-4e1a-8997-400a7aa150c3
cTime=1553838338130
storageType=NAME_NODE
blockpoolID=BP-1421744029-x.x.x.x-1553838338130
layoutVersion=-63
```

Considering the slave and master should have same clusterID, Correct me if I am wrong. 
The configuration seems to be working correctly but I am getting error in logs at `logs/hadoop-cassandra-datanode-localnosql1.log` and `logs/hadoop-cassandra-datanode-localnosql2.log`

```
2019-03-29 11:25:44,009 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for Block pool BP-954411427-x.x.x.y-1553838281164 (Datanode Uuid 4b90bebb-3c34-43d5-8285-6ec6dfefc0a7) service to localnosql1/x.x.x.x:8020 Blockpool ID mismatch: previously connected to Blockpool ID BP-954411427-x.x.x.y-1553838281164 but now connected to Blockpool ID BP-1421744029-x.x.x.x-1553838338130  
2019-03-29 11:25:49,010 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for Block pool BP-954411427-x.x.x.y-1553838281164 (Datanode Uuid 4b90bebb-3c34-43d5-8285-6ec6dfefc0a7) service to localnosql1/x.x.x.x:8020 Blockpool ID mismatch: previously connected to Blockpool ID BP-954411427-x.x.x.y-1553838281164 but now connected to Blockpool ID BP-1421744029-x.x.x.x-1553838338130  
2019-03-29 11:25:54,012 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for Block pool BP-954411427-x.x.x.y-1553838281164 (Datanode Uuid 4b90bebb-3c34-43d5-8285-6ec6dfefc0a7) service to localnosql1/x.x.x.x:8020 Blockpool ID mismatch: previously connected to Blockpool ID BP-954411427-x.x.x.y-1553838281164 but now connected to Blockpool ID BP-1421744029-x.x.x.x-1553838338130  
2019-03-29 11:25:59,013 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for Block pool BP-954411427-x.x.x.y-1553838281164 (Datanode Uuid 4b90bebb-3c34-43d5-8285-6ec6dfefc0a7) service to localnosql1/x.x.x.x:8020 Blockpool ID mismatch: previously connected to Blockpool ID BP-954411427-x.x.x.y-1553838281164 but now connected to Blockpool ID BP-1421744029-x.x.x.x-1553838338130  
2019-03-29 11:26:04,014 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for Block pool BP-954411427-x.x.x.y-1553838281164 (Datanode Uuid 4b90bebb-3c34-43d5-8285-6ec6dfefc0a7) service to localnosql1/x.x.x.x:8020 Blockpool ID mismatch: previously connected to Blockpool ID BP-954411427-x.x.x.y-1553838281164 but now connected to Blockpool ID BP-1421744029-x.x.x.x-1553838338130
```

What these error logs are suggesting?

**Does the blockpool ID on the all master and slave nodes need to be same like clusterId**, If yes how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to format namenode twice? Ideally, in multinode configuration, there is one namenode and many datanodes. 
While setting up for the first time, you initialize namenode by "`hdfs namenode -format`" then you start datanodes and it works fine.

If you are trying multi-master configuration (multiple namenode running at same time), them i am not sure this will work.

If you are trying active-standby configuration for namenode, you may try below steps

[Hadoop Namenode HA setup](https://www.edureka.co/blog/how-to-set-up-hadoop-cluster-with-hdfs-high-availability/)

Comment: Thanks for the link. It greatly increased my understanding.